# Find substing in list of srtings

Tags: search, substring, clickhouse

I've got 2 tables:
main with urls (ixbt.com,google.com/gen_204 etc)
filter with part of urls (like 204, gen etc.)
I need to find, if cell from main contains any row from filter and 
realization in Clickhouse is out of my mind.

```sql
create table dfgsdfgdfgdfghdfhj56uy567yrthfdghdfgujrtyu456ueyhghfjfghjfghu567ueryththjfghjgh(urls String) Engine=Memory as select * from values( ('ixbt.com'), ('google.com'), ('gen_204'));

create table zxcvfvbghfntyj6r7uertgsdfhy456u7rtumdft68tyuksey5425tgasddfgdfgdfgrty4566465756474656574567465yerh(filter String) Engine=Memory as select * from values( ('204'), ('gen'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dfgsdfgdfgdfghdfhj56uy567yrthfdghdfgujrtyu456ueyhghfjfghjfghu567ueryththjfghjgh, zxcvfvbghfntyj6r7uertgsdfhy456u7rtumdft68tyuksey5425tgasddfgdfgdfgrty4566465756474656574567465yerh
WHERE urls LIKE concat('%', filter, '%')



┌─urls────┬─filter─┐
│ gen_204 │ 204    │
│ gen_204 │ gen    │
└─────────┴────────┘
```

Comment: SQL Error [44] [07000]: Code: 44. DB::Exception: Argument at index 1 for function like must be constant: while executing 'FUNCTION like(urls : 0, concat('%', filter, '%') : 3) -> like(urls, concat('%', filter, '%')) UInt8 : 4'. (ILLEGAL_COLUMN) (version 22.5.1.2079 (official build))
, server ClickHouseNode(addr=http:10.179.15.51:8123, db=JanuaryRingBuffer)@1376168891

Comment: version 22.5 is out of support. https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-feature-3 22.6, Support non-constant pattern argument for LIKE, ILIKE and match functions.

Comment: you need to upgrade to 22.8